# Meteor js on Heroku with 2 or more dynos

Tags: javascript, heroku, websocket, meteor

Recently Heroku changed how their websockets work.  My MeteorJS app now fails to connect when I set the dyno slider to 2 or more.  This is the error I get in the browser console:

```
POST http://name.herokuapp.com/sockjs/414/ye3xmaq8/xhr_send 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't specifically need the performance of 2 dyno's, I just can't have the long time delay that occurs with 1 dyno after it goes to sleep.

Comment: Quick hack: you can add a worker instead.

Comment: Heroku doesn't have session affinity required for sockjs to run properly. And looks like your app cannot use websockets anyway?

Comment: Thanks Slava but I'm going to accept David's answer!

Comment: @imslavko is it still the case that meteor can only run on one heroku dyno?

Comment: I think they have implemented the sticky sessions, but I didn't try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Slava mentioned Heroku doesn't currently have Sticky Sessions so having more than one Dyno will not work. Without Sticky Sessions subsequent requests from the same client will go to different servos and Meteor stores publication state on the server so this doesn't work.

There is a solution to your specific problem of the Dyno going to sleep. First go to your app and then select "+ Get Add-ons" at the bottom, then search for "Heroku Scheduler." This addon will let you run a scheduled task. If that scheduled task is a 'curl' to your Heroku server every ten minutes or so then the Dyno won't go to sleep because it is seeing traffic (even though its form within heroku :)

The scheduled command might look like this:

```
curl http://www.yourHerokuAppUrl.com/ -s > /dev/null
```

Select a 1x dyno and a frequency of 'every 10 minutes' and you won't have the latency issues caused by waiting for the dyno to come back from sleeping.

Comment: That's good that you added an answer that actually addresses the primal problem :). Thanks David

Comment: The dyno sleep after 1 hour of inactivity, so you can schedule your curl request every 50mn.. https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/6/20/app_sleeping_on_heroku

Comment: It's true they sleep after an hour, so 50 minutes would be ideal, but last time I checked the Heroku Scheduler add on only allowed you to select 3 options for frequency: daily, hourly, every 10 minutes. That's why I said to select 10 minutes.

Comment: where do you define this task? I tried to define a short script in my meteor app, but when I create the scheduled job the script can't be located

Answer (score 2):

Just to update the answer.

Heroku [supports session affinity](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity) (or sticky sessions) since April 2015, and you can use many dynos on your Meteor app

Just enable it with

```
$ heroku labs:enable http-session-affinity
```